# How do I fix a bug caused by polymorphism?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, game-engine

My program bugs out on the following line:

```
RAT_Entity* ecm = new RAT_EntityCustomModel();
ecm->Init(entities.size(), resourceManager->getCustomMesh(meshURL));
```

It should initialize a child entity, but instead it breaks my engine.

The headers for RAT_Entity and RAT_EntityCustomModel are as follows:

```
#ifndef RAT_ENTITY_H
#define RAT_ENTITY_H

#include <iostream>

namespace RAT_ENGINE
{
    class RAT_Entity
    {
    public:
        RAT_Entity();
        ~RAT_Entity();

        virtual void Init(int argID, void* argVoid);
        virtual void CleanUp();

        int getID() const;

        virtual void PrintIO() const;
    protected:
        int id;
    };
}

#endif
```

and

```
#ifndef RAT_ENTITYCUSTOMMODEL_H
#define RAT_ENTITYCUSTOMMODEL_H

#include "RAT_Entity.h"
#include "RAT_CustomMesh.h"

namespace RAT_ENGINE
{
    class RAT_EntityCustomModel : public RAT_Entity
    {
    public:
        RAT_EntityCustomModel();
        ~RAT_EntityCustomModel();

        void Init(int argID, RAT_CustomMesh* argMesh);
        void CleanUp();

        RAT_CustomMesh* getMesh() const;

        void PrintIO() const;
    private:
        RAT_CustomMesh* mesh;
    };
}

#endif
```

As you can see, `void RAT_EntityCustomModel::Init(int argID, RAT_CustomMesh* argMesh)` inherits this function from `virtual void RAT_Entity::Init(int argID, void* argVoid)`. I needed to do this because otherwise I would get the following error:

> 1>e:\rat_engine\rat_engine\rat_engine\rat_entitymanager.cpp(34): error
>   C2660: 'RAT_ENGINE::RAT_Entity::Init' : function does not take 2
>   arguments

But now my engine breaks when calling the child's function. How can I fix this?

Comment: For the future: remove all unnecessary code, because it decreases readability (for example PrintIO, getMesh, private mesh etc are irrelevant to your question). How does look the command which causes the "function does not take 2 arguments" error?

Comment: All I can see "inconsistent naming conventions", and no implementation of polymorphism!

Comment: Unless `RAT_CustomMesh*` is the same as `void*`, they are not the same function and the base class fucntion will be called. Virtual functions must have exactly the same parameters in the base and derived classes.

Comment: The `Init` in the derived class *hides* the one in the base class, because the signatures do not match. This is not necessarily the root of the compiler error, but it is an error nonetheless. Also, your base class needs a virtual destructor.

Comment: Adding to what @BoPersson said, cv qualifiers must be the same too. `void foo()` is not the same as `void foo() const`. And anything called `foo` in a derived type would hide the base's `foo()` function.

Comment: You need a virtual destructor for your base class.

Comment: You should move `Init` and `CleanUp` into your class' constructor and destructor. That's what they're for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bug results from the fact that

```
RAT_Entity::Init
```

and

```
RAT_EntityCustomModel::Init
```

have different signatures. As a result, the latter function does not override the first one. If you pass in a `void*` pointer, then `RAT_Entity::Init` will be called. You, however, expect that `RAT_EntityCustomModel::Init` is called.

For fixing these kinds of bugs, I highly recommend using the override keyword that was introduced in C++11, i.e. change the signature in `RAT_EntityCustomModel::Init` to

```
void Init(int argID, RAT_CustomMesh* argMesh) override;
```

The compiler will complain about this kind of error then. You need a C++11 compliant compiler, however.

Comment: When I add `override` to the declaration I get the following error message:
1>e:\rat_engine\rat_engine\rat_engine\rat_entitycustommodel.h(15): error C3668: 'RAT_ENGINE::RAT_EntityCustomModel::Init' : method with override specifier 'override' did not override any base class methods

But it looks exactly like your example: `void Init(int argID, RAT_CustomMesh* argMesh) override;`

Comment: Is it because my compiler isn't C++11 compatible?

Comment: @Friso1990: No, this is the error message that you were waiting for. It is supposed to help you by telling you that your definition of ``RAT_EntityCustomModel::Init`` did not  override any base class methods. Now you know that you either have to change the method definition in ``RAT_EntityCustomModel`` or in one of its base classes. The signatures for the two methods ``Init`` definitions must match by either changing ``RAT_CustomMesh*`` to ``void*`` or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

You've got deeper problems.

Your `RAT_Entity` and `RAT_EntityCustomModel` need different things in order to be initialised correctly, possibly completely different things, I can't tell.

The commonality between them is they need something, the difference is they want different things, a `RAT_CustomMesh` for example.

If the things they need aren't completely different, i.e. they both need some kind of mesh, then you can pass `RAT_Mesh` as the parameter in the base class instead of `void*`.

If they are initialised with completely different things, then the `Entity` needs to decide what it needs. In that case pass a resource manager, a bit modified from the one you have already, from which the entity can request what it needs.

```
class ResourceManager {
public:
    RAT_PlainMesh* getPlainMesh();
    RAT_CustomMesh* getCustomMesh();
};
```

And the base `RAT_Entity` init function:

```
class RAT_Entity
{
public:
    virtual void Init(int argID, ResourceManager& resourceManager);
    //...
};
```